in django i try to get a word collection but my function return "nothing"
I have a foreign language learning page, which also has a memory game that works by displaying a random word. I would like to use the same database as the game to display a "word: translation" dictionary with all the words in alphabetical order. thanks
this is my views.py file
from django.shortcuts import render
from cards.models import Card

def lexicon(request):
    card_list = Card.objects.all()
    context = {'card_list': card_list}
    return render(request, 'lexicon/lexicon.html', context)

and this is my html
        <main>
            <div class="container-small">
                {% for card in card_list %}
                    <p>{{ card.question }}</p>
                    <p>{{ card.answer }}</p>
                {% endfor %} 
            </div>    
        </main>

my db.sqlite3 file have this structure
database structure

card_list = Card.objects.order_by('question')
Try this, it will return the card list by the 'question' field in alphabetical order

So exactly how does the Card model looks like?

https://i.sstatic.net/hjzBm.png

Try to modify your view to retrieve all the words from the database and pass them to the template in alphabetical order. You can try this by arranging the queryset alphabetically by using the word field.
def lexicon(request):
   
    card_list = Card.objects.all().order_by('question')
    context = {'card_list': card_list}
    return render(request, 'lexicon/lexicon.html', context)

N.B:Make sure your Card model has appropriate fields for the word and it's translation.

Card Model is fine. I already use it successfully in the memory game

    <h1>{{ card.question }}</h1>
        {% if not check_card %}
    {% else %}
    <p class="hoverable">{{ card.answer }}</p>
</div>


I modified view aswell.
change this
card_list = Card.objects.all()
to this
card_list = Card.objects.all().order_by('question')

My problem is not necessarily the order but the fact that it doesn't display anything
